# Visit each element in HTMLCollection/NodeList

Tags: javascript, dom

I would like to visit each element (using only JavaScript, no jQuery or any other JavaScript library) in live HTMLCollection or NodeList, for example collection returned by `var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('class-name');`

If DOM is not changing then I can do this with `for` loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
{
    //Do something with elements[i]
}
```

But what to do in situation when `for` loop is still running and there is addition or deletion of elements with class `class-name`. If an `element` has been deleted or added then indices will change.

So, how can I make sure that while `for` loop is running, no `element` in `elements` is missed using JavaScript only.

Comment: If the DOM changes, it's because the code you have in your loop changes it. Can't you manage to track the changes you do ?

Comment: What if there is some other script running which changes the DOM?

Comment: It kind-of depends on what you're doing.  One possible solution would be to make a copy of the NodeList into a simple JavaScript array. *edit* There cannot be any other script running while your loop is running; JavaScript doesn't work that way (in a browser, anyway).

Comment: dystroy is correct. all javascript in a browser runs in a single thread

Comment: What do you mean some other script running ? The JS engine handles only one script thread at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only one script running at a given time. The only changes that can happen to the DOM while your script is running are the ones made by your script. All other tasks, events, etc. will patiently wait for your script to finish execution.

So

- don't worry for external changes to the DOM, there is none
- track the changes your code made

and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the for loop is not asynchronous so the elements can't change, as the for loop gets fully executed before the change will happen d, or the change should happen before the for loop.

Comment: This isn't really true with a NodeList. Those are "live", so activity in the loop (changes to the DOM) can make the list gain or lose elements.

Answer (score 0):

The "live" collections are just really awkward default that keep surprising people. I suggest you simply use `querySelectorAll` which is not only more supported than gEBCN but returns a snapshot instead of a "live" collection.

I see that even the notion that the collection is "live" causes confusion. It is not live, but basically the properties are getters e.g. `[i]` actually calls `.item(i)` - the method dynamically then retrieves the element which makes the collection appear live.

And there's more. Some people keep using these methods because they wrongly think they are substantially faster due to broken benchmarks. In those benchmarks, only direct method calls are compared and it is not considered that "live" collections do not do any work until you try to retrieve the elements.